# How to count all guilds member discord.js v12

Tags: javascript

So that's the way to count all the guilds member in one message!

```js
const math = require('mathjs');

const guildCount = client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.memberCount);
const reslut = math.evaluate(guildCount.join("+"));
message.channel.send(`Your Bot serve: \`${reslut}\` Member!`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code adds the `memberCountz of each guild to the` cal`variable, but you are using the`guildCount`variable for the sum, which contains nothing since your`.map` callback is not returning anything.

So either

```
const math = require('mathjs');

const guildCount = client.guilds.cache.map(g => {return g.memberCount});
const result = math.evaluate(guildCount.join("+"));
message.channel.send(`Your Bot serve: \`${result}\` Member!`)
```

or

```
const math = require('mathjs');

const cal = [];
const guildCount = client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {cal.push(g.memberCount)});
const result = math.evaluate(cal.join("+"));
message.channel.send(`Your Bot serve: \`${result}\` Member!`)
```

---

But you can do the sum with a simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), no need for an additional package.

```js
const result = client.guilds.cache.reduce((total, guild) => sum + guild.memberCount, 0);
message.channel.send(`Your Bot serve: \`${result}\` Member!`)
```

Comment: yeah i figured out its was not working because i edit some lines before post it here and i didn't test it , so thanks for correct me!